# Perl performance when reading and writing the same file

Tags: perl, file-io

Is there any noticeable performance difference between these two ways of reading/writing a user file with Perl, on Linux?

Option 1:

```
open (READFILE, '<:utf8', "users/$_[0]") or die ("no read users/$_[0]");
    # Do the reading
close (READFILE) or die;
# Do more stuff
open (WRITEFILE, '>:utf8', "users/$_[0]") or die ("no write users/$_[0]"); flock (WRITEFILE, 2) or die ("no lock users/$_[0]");
    # Do the writing
close (WRITEFILE) or die;
```

Option 2:

```
open (USERFILE, '+<:utf8', "users/$_[0]") or die ("no open users/$_[0]"); flock (USERFILE, 2) or die ("no lock users/$_[0]");
    # Do the reading
    # Do more stuff
    seek (USERFILE, 0, 0); truncate (USERFILE, 0);
    # Do the writing
close (USERFILE) or die ("no write users/$_[0]");
```

The user files are not big, typically 20-40 lines or 2-4 KB each.

And would there be other reasons for choosing option 1 or 2 (or a 3rd option)?

Comment: What prevent you from test and measure?

Comment: @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil, you have a point. Will benchmark in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a benchmark which you can use to test it, I suspect that getting a new file descriptor is the part that takes longer if you `close` and then `open` again.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use open qw(:encoding(utf8) :std);

use Benchmark qw<cmpthese>;
my $text = <<TEXT;
I had some longer text here, but for better readability, just
these two lines.
TEXT


cmpthese(10_000,{
     close => sub{
       open my $file, '<',"bla" or die "$!";
       my @array = <$file>;
       close $file or die;
       open $file, '>',"bla" or die "$!";
       $file->print($text)
     },
     truncate => sub {
       open my $file, '+<',"bla" or die "$!";
       my @array = <$file>;
       seek $file,0,0;
       truncate $file, 0;
       $file->print($text)
     },
     truncate_flock => sub {
       open my $file, '+<',"bla" or die "$!";
       flock $file, 2;
       my @array = <$file>;
       seek $file,0,0;
       truncate $file, 0;
       $file->print($text)
     },

});
```

Output on my machine:

```
                 Rate          close truncate_flock       truncate
close          2703/s             --           -15%           -17%
truncate_flock 3175/s            17%             --            -3%
truncate       3257/s            21%             3%             --
```

A higher rate is better. Using `close` is 1.17 times slower.
But it heavily depends on how long your `more stuff` takes, since you're `flock`ing the file in your `truncate` example and if another program is trying to access this file it may be slowed down because of that.

Comment: `use 5.01;` is technically correct but misleads the reader into thinking you require Perl 5.1.  `use v5.10;` is much clearer.  If you have some aversion to the v format (backwards compatibility for extraordinarily old Perls?) at least say `use 5.010;`

Comment: @Schwern: Actually I'd prefer the `v5.10 ` variant, but I don't like the warning. In this case, I'm actually not sure if need it, so I'll remove it here.

Comment: I rarely worked on machines with 5.010 and there was a compatibility warning, but they recently updated.

Comment: Thanks for doing the benchmarking for me. I'll accept this answer one of these days unless someone adds an answer with more insights.